# Hi..Can anyone help me resolve the error with following piece of code below?

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR

svr = SVR(kernel = "rbf")

svr.fit(X_train,Y_train)

Y_pred = sc_X.inverse_transform(svr.predict(X_test))


pd.DataFrame(Y_pred, columns = ['Price']).to_excel("Final_Pred.xlsx", index = False)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2671,) (12,) (2671,)
```